# How to grill eggplant and tomato?

Tags: vegetables, grilling

I have a infrared oven. I want to use it to grill eggplant and tomato. I have no clue why restaurants can do that so good. Every time I do grill them, it just like to put them into reheat. Any advice?

Comment: grilling as in broiling ?

Comment: Your oven will bake or broil - neither imitate a proper grill. This is probably why you're not getting the desired results! If you cannot get a proper grill, you may be able to find single-use/disposable grills at your local walmart or similar store. Make sure you use them outside though!

Comment: @SnakeDoc There's a difference in English language use of the word *grill* in the US compared to the UK. What Americans call a broiler, we in the UK and some other English speaking countries often simply call it a grill -  in fact, it's short for a "salamander grill", and the heat comes from the top. The terms broil/broiler are rarely if ever used in the UK.

Comment: @BillyKerr That's interesting, I never knew. You learn something new every day! Thanks for weighing in.

Comment: No idea what problem you are tying to solve.   What does this mean?   "just like to put them into reheat"  Describe the specific characteristics that are not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

*If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail...*  **;-)**

You have an infra-red oven and that is great to broil eggplant and tomato, but will not give you anything close to a grilled effect so:

- If you want to broil:

  - slice up the veggies
  - add a sprinkle of oil and some nice fresh herbs on top
  - put them in the infra-red oven
- If you want to grill them:

  - buy a grill

<sub>Please don't kill the messenger?  Pretty please???</sub>

Comment: 'grill' and 'broil' don't have the same meanings in all English dialects.  In some, the meanings are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that 'grill' in your sense is top heat.  If so, some recommendations:

- Leave the oven door slightly ajar.  This will keep moisture from building up in the oven, and steaming the ingredients.  (gas ovens always have *some* venting, but they can still get a build-up of steam; electric ovens will switch off if they get too hot)
- Get the food as close to the heating element as you can.  That will get you the layer of char on top, that you won't get if it's 6" (15cm) or more from element.  I aim for about 1" (2.5cm) from the element, although a little bit more for thick cuts of meat.  (Steaks plumps up as they cook, and they can reach up and touch the element if you're too close)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the infrared oven, but I get a pretty good results using high heat (around 250°C) in the normal oven.